# how to pass html tag value to flask

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

supposed this is  main jinja templates

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <a href="{{url_for('info')}}"><h5 class="card-title">{{ book[0] }}</h5></a>
{% endblock %}
```

So is there any way to passed the value of  tag to my routes when it is click

Answer (score 0):

I typically use JavaScript for this with an onclick="someMethod()".

```
<div onclick="passValues('{{my_value}}')">{{my_content}}</div>
```

The JavaScript method can then deal with it appropriately.

```
function passValues(value) {
    window.location = "/some-route/" + value;
}
```

Comment: actually i m trying to pass list of values, i tried your code but it didn't gave me the result

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: So you want to take a list of values that is saved to a Jinja variable and pass it to a flask route if I understand correctly?

Comment: In the JavaScript function, just iterate through the list of values you pass it and add those to the request url ("?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c") OR just make a POST call and pass the values in via the request body.